# How to split a file into multiple files based on condition match with line numbers starting from beginning in all split files in UNIX?

Tags: unix, awk

For this I used a command like below using awk

```
awk '/H.*/{x="F"++i;next}{print NR-1 "," $0 > x;}' words.txt
```

which splits into multiple files when any Header pattern matches.

```
words.txt
Header
LLLL
AAAA
Header
SSSS
DDDD
```

Now after splitting am getting output with above command

```
File1.txt
1. LLLL
2. AAAA
File2.txt
3. SSSS
4. DDDD
```

What am expecting is line numbers starting from 1 in each file like below

```
File1.txt
1. LLLL
2. AAAA
File2.txt
1. SSSS
2. DDDD
```

Comment: @oguzismail here, input is words.txt. And i have mentioned the contents of words.txt. And I want to create new file for each "Header" data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case you need to print the count vice(matching your conditions one) then use following.

```
awk '/H.*/{count=1;close(x);x="F"++i;next}{print count++ "," $0 > x;}' words.txt
```

Add `close` also to avoid error which gives us sometimes *"too many files opened"*

***Explanation:*** Adding explanation of above code too now.

```
awk '                             ##Starting awk program here.
/H.*/{                            ##Checking condition from H.* to till everything it covers in line.
  count=1                         ##Setting variable named count value to 1 here.
  close(x)                        ##Closing the file(in case it is opened) whose value is variable x value. To avoid too many opened files error.
  x="F"++i                        ##Creating variable x whose value is character F with increasing value of variable F each time with 1.
  next                            ##next will skip all further statements.
}
{                                 ##Following statements will be executed when above condition is NOT TRUE.
  print count++ "," $0 > x        ##Printing variable count value with comma and current line value into file named x here.
}
' words.txt                       ##Mentioning Input_file name here.
```

Comment: Thanks for quick help. You can create a file e.g., words.txt and copy the contents of words.txt that i have mentioned in the question description. Anyway I've tested your command. IT gives same as mine. The line numbers are not appearing in each file from 1. It just takes the next number.

<br/>
1.LLLL
2.WWWW
3.EEEE
<br/>
4.LLLL
5.WWWW
6.EEEE

Comment: Nope not working. I tried both. same result. No luck. 

<br/> 1.LLLL 2.WWWW 3.EEEE 

<br/> 4.LLLL 5.WWWW 6.EEEE

Comment: @BhabadyutiBal, sure added it now for reference. Let us clean our comments too for clear post too :)

Answer (score 1):

Here

```
awk '/^Header$/{close(f); f="File"++n".txt"; l=0; next}{print ++l". "$0 > f}' words.txt
```

Result

```
$ cat File1.txt 
1. LLLL
2. AAAA
$ 
$ cat File2.txt 
1. SSSS
2. DDDD
```